# SQL classify the customer_income_am column

Tags: mysql, sql

This code is used to classify the customer as a "H" for High if the customer has a  yearly income above $55,000;   "M" for Medium if the customer has a  yearly income above $40,000;   "L" for Low if the customer has a  yearly income above $15,000;   "P" for Poor if the customer has a  yearly income less than $15,000;

```
insert into CUST_INCOME_AM
```

I don't know if it is a update or some other SQL code. the data is in the column but if I need to make it do the calculation before It will be pulling that data from ODS_CUSTOMER.

[WHERE CUST_INCOME_AM is][1]

i need to change it so it is represented by the letters above.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oeF9.jpg

Comment: If the question is not clear, ask your teacher for explanation. Please also do read: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I don't know how to write the code itself. I don't know if it is a where statement or something else.it is a very individual project that this is just a piece from.

Comment: show us more.  show output of `show create table yourtablename` for the relevant tables.  and only you can tell us if you want to update some column with the classification code or just have it returned from one or more selects

Comment: hopefully the pic helps. i need to change that column to represent the letters based on the number amount

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generated column:

```
alter table t add cust_income_classification varchar(255) as
    (case when CUST_INCOME_AM >= 55000 then 'H'
          when CUST_INCOME_AM >= 40000 then 'M'
          when CUST_INCOME_AM >= 15000 then 'L'
          else 'P'
     end);
```

Comment: What about in a situation where the CUST_INCOME_AM is already in the table? what would add change to?

Comment: would i put on additionally to alter column?

Comment: You can drop the column and re-add it as a computed column.